# Remove folders from path in SQLite DB value

Tags: php, html, sqlite, path

I have an SQLite database that contains URL's to images, for example dbvalues: `img/bmo/image1.jpg`and `img/bmo/image2.gif`.

I then have a function that makes thumbnails of theese images an places them in `img/thumbs/`, keeping the original filename.
Then I use SELECT and foreach to display all the images listed in the database. and use 
`<img src="<?php echo $objekt['image']; ?>" class="center" alt="<?php echo $objekt['title'];?>">`
 to do so.

Now, How would I do to display the thumbnails instead of the source image? I other words, replacing the folder path from the db- value with another path but keep the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the answer:

`<?php $imageFile = basename($objekt['image']); ?>
<img src="img/thumbs/<?php echo $imageFile;?>" class="center" alt="<?php echo $objekt['title'];?>">`